# Measuring Height of Multi-Line TextView

Tags: android, textview, multiline

I have created a custom view with a bunch of subviews. This subview may show some or all of its children depending on the space available. Secondary elements that do not fit should be hidden. One of the subviews is a multi-line `TextView` that may or may not fit.

For this to work, I need to calculate the height of the `TextView`. It's understood that it should be done when the view is fully inflated, so I'm setting the text in an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` and then try to get the measures.

This works nicely e.g. for an `ImageView` but the `TextView`'s height seems to be the same no matter how many lines of text it shows. So neither `textView.getHeight()` nor `textView.getMeasuredHeight()` will get me the actual height of a multi-line `TextView`. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood this correctly, you call `setText` on the `TextView` in the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` callback?

At that time, the height hasn't been calculated yet.

You should either:

1) Set the text immediately, before the callback. Then get the height in the callback.

2) Call `post(Runnable)` on the TextView while inside the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` callback. Inside the runnable, you can get the TextView height.

Comment: Yes. In `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, I first called `setText()` and then checked the height. I now moved `setText()` to the activity's `onCreate()` according to your first suggestion and it works. My conditions for hiding the view need some fine-tuning but that was not subject of the question. Thank you for the solution!